# Cannot send messages over stomp using Spring messaging

Tags: javascript, java, spring, stomp, spring-messaging

I am trying to send and handle message from browser over STOPM using spring-messaging. But message is not sent.

Some code now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketStompConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/marcopolo").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

As you can see i am using embedded springs simple broker.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/sockjs-client/1.0.2/sockjs.min.js}"/>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/stomp-websocket/2.3.3/stomp.min.js}"/>
    <script>
        function doSmth(){
            var sock = new SockJS('/spittr/marcopolo');

            var stomp = Stomp.over(sock);

            var payload = JSON.stringify({'message': 'Marco !'});

            stomp.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {
                stomp.send('/app/marcopolo', {}, payload);
            });
            var dupa = 'dupa';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="doSmth();">Connect</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When i am trying to debug script part in firefox debug never reach part:

```
stomp.send('/app/marcopolo', {}, payload);
```

maybe stomp cannot connect?

stomp and sock objects are created properly.

```
@Controller
public class MarcoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/marcop", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMarcoPolo(){
        return "sockjstest";
    }

    @MessageMapping(value = "/marcopolo")
    public void handleShout(Shout incoming){
        System.out.println(incoming.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When i call doSmth() function and try to breakpoint handleShout(Shout incoming) function i cannot catch that breakpoint. Function is never called.

Do you see what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ehh solution of that problem is really easy :)
Just used wrong class to extend my WebSocketStompConfig.
Used: AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
Should be: AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer